# How to pass 2 or more array criteria in SUMIFS formula?

Tags: excel

I have a below table as below

```
A   B   C
a   aa  1
a   aa  1
a   dd  1
a   aa  1
b   aa  1
b   bb  1
b   aa  1
b   bb  1
c   cc  1
c   bb  1
c   bb  1
c   cc  1
d   cc  1
d   aa  1
d   bb  1
d   cc  1
```

When i put the formula

> =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C1:C16,A1:A16,{"a","b","c"}))

it returns 12
However when i put

> =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C1:C16,A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},B1:B16,{"aa","bb"}))

it returns only 5

Can one one help me with this. I dont wnat to use multi formula like

> =SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C1:C16,A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},B1:B16,"aa"})) + SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C1:C16,A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},B1:B16,"bb"}))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer that i was expecting from another site.
Thanks http://www.excelforum.com/members/30486.html

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIFS(C1:C16,A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},B1:B16,{"aa";"bb"}))

Answer (score 0):

I would use this one:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},0)*MATCH(B1:B16,{"aa","bb"},0))*(C1:C16))
```

or, if `C1:C16` always contains only `1`, simply:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},0)*MATCH(B1:B16,{"aa","bb"},0)))
```

[image]

Comment: One question. What if i have a third column and want to add that as a criteria in the formula

Comment: use something like this: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},0)*MATCH(B1:B16,{"aa","bb"},0)*MATCH(E1:E16,{"someVal","someAnotherVal"},0))*(C1:C16))`

Comment: i got it =SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1:A16,{"a","b","c"},0)*MATCH(B1:B16,A19:B19,0)*MATCH(C1:C16,{"aaa"},0))*(D1:D16))

Comment: one Problem.. i use to pass file path and sheet name to the SumIFs INDIRECT("'"&FilePath&Sheets&"'!$AG$231:$AG$280"), can we do the same with Match?

Comment: it seems to me the same as for sumifs: `MATCH(INDIRECT("'"&FilePath&Sheets&"'!$AG$231:$AG$280"),{"a","b","c"},0)`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51376/discussion-between-sathish-and-simoco)